# Proof of $\bigcap_{n\in I}A(n) = (-1,0) \cup (1,2)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Say $I = \mathbb{N} \setminus \{0, 1\}$ and

$$A(n) = \left\{x \in \mathbb{R}\,\middle|\, −1−
\frac{1}{n}
< x \leq
\frac{1}{n}
\text{ or } 1−
\frac{1}{n} \leq x < 2−
\frac{1}{n}
\right\}$$
with $n \in I$.

What is $\bigcap_{n\in I}A(n)$ equivalent to? And proof?

---

$A(2) = (-1.5<x\leq0.5)$ or $(0.5\leq x\leq1.5)$

$A(3) = (-1.3<x0.33333...)$ or $(0.6≤x≤1.666...)$

$\dots$

$A(1000000)=(-1<x <0)$ or $(1<x<2)$

We see that if $n$ is arbitrarily large enough: $A(n)= (-1,0) \cup (1,2)$
As distribution laws of indexed families apply:

$$\bigcap_{i\in I}(A_i ∪ B_i) \supseteq \left(\bigcap_{i\in I} A_i\right) \cup \left(\bigcap_{i\in I} B_i\right)$$

We have

$$ \begin{align*} \bigcap_{n\in I}A(n) &= \left[\bigcap_{n\in I}A(n)\left(−1− \frac{1}{n} < x \leq \frac{1}{n}\right)\right] \cup \left[\bigcap_{n\in I}A(n)\left(1− \frac{1}{n} \leq x < 2− \frac{1}{n}\right)\right] \\
&= (-1,0) \cup (1,2) \end{align*} $$

Which direction can I go to prove it?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: It's **not** true that $\bigcap_{n\in I}A(n)=(-1,0)\cup(1,2)$, as for example $A(2)=\left(-\frac{3}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right]\cup\left[\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2}\right)$, and $(-1,0)\cup(1,2)\not\subseteq A(2)$.

Comment: You probably have some mistakes in your question, because the intersection of all those $A(n)$ is $[-1, 0] \cup [1,2)$. Please try to correct them if you want to receive an answer.

Comment: @AlexM. I 've double checked the question and it is really it.

Comment: @Lorago I 've check it and as I understand it right (−1, 0) ∪(1,2) ⊆ A(2) as the under bound ∣-1∣<∣-3/2∣ and the  upper bound 0<1/2 thus (-1,0) ⊆ (-3/2,1/2]

Comment: The second interval in my comment should be $[1, \frac 3 2]$, not $[1,2)$.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Let me know if is ok for you.

Comment: @AntonioJPan thank you for the comment! The interval [−1,0]∪[1,3/2) seems to be correct. Only the inclusion of -1 and 0 in the 1st interval doesn't make sense cause -1/n can be very close to 0, but not 0; and 1/n can't be 0. The same goes for the inclusion of 1 in the second interval.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense. Because -1,0 and 1 belongs to the intersection of all the family $\{A(n)\}$.
On the other hand, if you find the answer useful, I would be happy if you mark it as valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I think you have a typo. In the definition of $A(n)$ it should be $x<2+\frac{1}{n}$.

Having said that, you need to prove that $\bigcap_{n\in I}A(n) \subseteq (-1,0) \cup (1,2)$ and $ (-1,0) \cup (1,2) \subseteq \bigcap_{n\in I}A(n)$.
The second statement is trivial.

To prove $\bigcap_{n\in I}A(n) \subseteq (-1,0) \cup (1,2)$, suppose $y\in \bigcap_{n\in I}A(n)$ and $y \notin (-1,0) \cup (1,2)$. Then it must be $y<-1$ or $0<y<1$ or $2<y$.

Suppose $y>2$. Then there exists $\bar{n}\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $y>2+\frac{1}{n}$, for example you can take any $\bar{n}>\frac{1}{y-2}$. Therefore, you have a contradiction, since it cannot be $y\in A(\bar{n})$.

Now you must proceed in the same way with the other cases...

---

If what is wrong is the title of the question instead of the definition of $A(n)$, then we have
$$
\bigcap_{n\in I}A(n) = [-1,0] \cup [1,\frac{3}{2}). 
$$
To prove that you must use the same approach than above. On the one hand, $[-1,0] \cup [1,\frac{3}{2})$ is trivially contained in $\bigcap_{n\in I}A(n)$, because it is contained in $A(n)$ for every $n\geq 2$.

On the other hand, suppose $y\in \bigcap_{n\in I}A(n)$ but $y\notin [-1,0] \cup [1,\frac{3}{2})$. There are several reasons for $y$ not belonging to $[-1,0] \cup [1,\frac{3}{2})$, and you have to show that all of them lead to a contradiction as I did above. For example, if the reason is  $y<-1$ then you can take $n_0>\frac{1}{-1-y}$ and then $\frac{1}{n_0}<-1-y$ and therefore $y<-1-\frac{1}{n_0}$. So $y\notin A(n_0)$, what is a contradiction.

Comment: In the current formulation of the question (which probably contains some mistakes), the intersection of all those $A(n)$ is $[-1, 0] \cup [1,2)$.

Comment: Well, $A(2)=(-1.5,1.5)$, so I don't think the intersection contains, for example, 1.8

Comment: Yep, you are right and the intersection is $[-1,0] \cup [1, \frac 3  2]$.

Comment: I think it is $[-1,0]\cup [1,\frac{3}{2})$

Comment: Yes, of course, because $\frac 3 2 \notin A(2)$.

Answer (score 0):

Probably $[-1;0)\cup(1;2]$

Let $\forall \epsilon \in [-1;0)$ show that $\exists n \in I, \epsilon \in A(n)$.

Since $\forall n \in I, -1 - \frac{1}{n} < -1$ obviously $x \in A(n) \Rightarrow x \in [-1;+\infty)$

For any $\epsilon \in \mathbb{R}$ there exists $\frac{1}{n} \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $|\epsilon| > |\frac{1}{n}|$ (you can check this by looking at cases $|\epsilon| \geq 1$ and $|\epsilon| < 1$). Then $\epsilon \in A(n)$

You can show in the same way that for any number y less then -1 exists n such that $y \not\in A(n)$.

I believe that similar algorithm works for $(1;2]$

Comment: In the current formulation of the question (which probably contains some mistakes), the intersection of all those $A(n)$ is $[-1, 0] \cup [1,2)$.

Comment: Yeah, now I see that my answer and solution are completely wrong

Comment: The second interval in my comment should be $[1, \frac 3 2]$, not $[1,2)$.